How to disable Self-Registration for AWS Cognito User Pool from Terraform?
I'm trying to terraform my AWS Cognito User Pool configuration. I'm using federated authentication and would like to disable user self-registration / sign-up. How can I do this via terraform?

set the allow_admin_create_user_only setting in the aws_cognito_user_pool resource to true

Thank you! :) Completely overlooked that in the docs

let me put the docs in answer :)

answer is resolved in the comment, this is related doc for future if anyone requires information:
solution:

set the allow_admin_create_user_only setting in the
aws_cognito_user_pool resource to true

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool
